# proving continuity of homotopy

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose that $F:X\times{}I\rightarrow{}Y$ is continuous. For each $t\in{I}$ define $f_t:X\rightarrow{Y}$ by $f_t(x)=F(x,t)$. I'm trying to prove that $f_t$ is continuous.

I've tried taking open balls in Y for a fixed t and considering their corrosponding pre-images but this seems like a lot of work. Am I missing something?

any tips or directions etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For a fixed $t\in I$, the inclusion $X\to X\times I, \ x\mapsto (x,t)$ is continuous.

Comment: Firstly will it suffice to just consider the commutative diagram of the inclusion map described above, $F$ and $f_t$? Secondly, I know the inclusion map above is obviously continuous, but how would one formally show this? Is it enough to say $X\times{\{t\}}\cong{X}$ for some fixed $t\in{[0,1]}$?